# Sorting 2 dimensional arrays in Java - skipping the first index

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, data-structures, multidimensional-array

I have a two-dimensional array in **Java** that looks like this:

**Each element/job has a:**

- Job number which is in **index[0]**;
- Job arrival time which is in **index[1]**; and
- Job burst time in **index[2]**

```
jobs[0][0] = 1
jobs[0][1] = 0
jobs[0][2] = 5

jobs[1][0] = 2
jobs[1][1] = 2
jobs[1][2] = 19

jobs[2][0] = 3
jobs[2][1] = 4
jobs[2][2] = 10
```

**First**, I wanted to sort them according to arrival time which is according to **index[1]** which fortunately I did by using this code:

```
Arrays.sort(jobs, new Comparator<int[]>(){
    public int compare(int[] a, int[] b) {
        return a[1] - b[1];
    }
});
```

---

Now, my problem is I want to sort it according to burst time which is according to index[2]. Here is the TWIST... How can I be able to sort it according to burst time (index[2]) skipping the first element?
I would like job[0] to remain on top of the array and sort the remaining elements by index[2] - burst time. Like this:

```
jobs[0][0] = 1
jobs[0][1] = 0
jobs[0][2] = 5

jobs[1][0] = 3
jobs[1][1] = 4
jobs[1][2] = 10

jobs[2][0] = 2
jobs[2][1] = 2
jobs[2][2] = 19
```

The jobs are being sorted by burst time with job1 remaining on top. **Implementing it by the code I provided above would be much better. Thanks**

Comment: too much of BOLD is hurting the eyes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trivial way would be:

```
int firstBurst = jobs[0][2];
jobs[0][2] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
Arrays.sort(jobs, new Comparator<int[]>(){
    public int compare(int[] a, int[] b) {
        // don't use subtraction, this can lead to underflows
        return a[2] < b[2] ? -1 : (a[2] == b[2] ? 0 : 1);
    }
});
jobs[0][2] = firstBurst;
```

Simply set the burst of the first item to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (the integer equivalent of minus infinity). That way, it guaranteed that the first item is the smallest, so after sorting it will still be the first element. After sorting, reset the burst of the first item to its original value.

**EDIT**

By checking the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) to verify that `Arrays.sort` is stable, I accidentally found the simplest version to solve this problem: use

```
Arrays.sort(T[] a,
            int fromIndex,
            int toIndex,
            Comparator<? super T> c)
```

then you can do this directly:

```
Arrays.sort(jobs, 1, jobs.length, new Comparator<int[]>(){
    public int compare(int[] a, int[] b) {
        // don't use subtraction, this can lead to underflows
        return a[2] < b[2] ? -1 : (a[2] == b[2] ? 0 : 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't the return look like this `return a[2] < b[2] ? -1 : (a[2] == b[2] ? 0 : 1);` ?

Comment: Sir, your code worked! thanks.can you have just a brief explanation about your code pls?

Comment: @bowmore it is, right? Or am I confused with `Collections.sort`?

Comment: It is a stable sort, just pointing out you have some logical coupling in this approach.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you should use collections instead of arrays. And second, you should not use an array when you could use an object:

```
public class Job {
    private int number;
    private int arrival;
    private int burst;

    // constructor and getters omitted for brevity.
}
```

You could then have a `List<Job>`, instead of an `int[][]`. Just by looking at the typeof the structure, it's already clearer and more readable. Having named attributes, potentially of different types, and being able to add behavior with methods, is a part of what OO is all about. Much more readable, safe and maintainable than an `int[]`.

The good news is that a List has much more features than an array. So you can for example, take a subList, and sort that subList:

```
List<Job> jobsExceptFirstOne = allJobs.subList(1);
Collections.sort(jobsExceptFirstOne, new Comparator<Job>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Job left, Job right) {
        return Integer.compare(left.getBurst(), right.getBurst());
    }
});
```

Voilà. Problem solved.

Comment: I appreciate your answer sir but unfortunately I dont know how to use LISTS and its quite a long code now and its kinda large change if I turn everything to LISTS :(

Comment: Then learn how to use them. It's something that any Java developer MUST know. Persisting with the bad design you have now will make things worse and worse. You'd better fix that ASAP.

Comment: Hopefully I will sir, thank you very much sir. I hope someday I'll be someone like you guys. professional developers. thank you very much sir

Answer (score 1):

As stated by others, you should be using smarter collections instead of arrays, if you *really* want to use current code, you can use something like:

```
final int[][] jobs = new int[][]{{1,0,5},{2,2,19},{3,4,10}};

 Arrays.sort(jobs, new Comparator<int[]>(){
    public int compare(int[] a, int[] b) {
        if(Arrays.equals(a, jobs[0]))
         return -1;
        else
         return a[2] - b[2];
    }
});

System.out.println(jobs[0][2]);
System.out.println(jobs[1][2]);
System.out.println(jobs[2][2]);
```

The only drawback is your array needs to be `final`.

Comment: it sorted out including job[0]

Comment: job[0] will always be at the head using this, wasn't that the intent?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there would be a way of using this:

```
final Integer job1 = Integer.valueOf(jobs[0][0]);
final Integer job2 = Integer.valueOf(jobs[0][1]);

return job1.compareTo(job2);
```

I dont really know if valueOf(jobs[0][0]) would be bigger then valueOf(jobs[0][1]), and I dont really know how they stand to one and another, but there must be a difference between them, and with that you should be a able to sort them according to if the returned number is bigger or smaller then the one of jobs[0][0], jobs[1][0], etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Comparator taht remembers the job number of the first job, and regards that as the smallest prior to checking burst time.

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<int[]> {

    private final int firstJob;

    public MyComparator(int firstJob) {
        this.firstJob = firstJob;
    }

    public int compare(int[] a, int[] b) {
        if (a[0] == b[0]) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (a[0] == firstJob) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (b[0] == firstJob) {
            return 1;
        }
        return Integer.compare(a[2], b[2]);
    }
}
```